# How to programmatically add options inside a select div tag?

Tags: php, html, select, html-select

what I am trying to do is, add options that are inside a select div tag pro-grammatically if that is possible at all.

This is my html code

```
 <select class="form-control multiplechose_questionTypes" name="selector[]" id="selector" > 
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
```

in my php script, i have a variable that takes a count from a passed in function

```
$count  = count_answers_belongToOne_question($questionNumber);
```

So let's say if the $count returned the value 2, I want to only show 2 options inside that select div tag. So based on what ever the value is in $count, I want it to update on the `<select>`.

Can anyone suggest me an idea or a solution on how to go about doing this

Comment: are the options dynamic? does that come from an array?

Comment: those options currently comes hardcoded, but I want it to come from database

Comment: it comes from that variable $count, and whatever the value that is that is how many options I want to be

Comment: If they are comming from the database, simply clear the select options everytime you render a new question and use LIMIT (if using mysql) in your sql syntax when you are selecting for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are nice way of doing this with PHP as mentioned on other answers but here is a simple javascript for updating HTML DOME select options

```
<script>
function updateSelect(options){

var x = document.getElementById("selector");

if (x.length > 0) {
    for (i = options; i < x.length+1; i++){
        x.remove(options);
    }
} 
}
window.onload = function (){updateSelect(2);}
</script>
```

you can set value of count in php at run time like

```
window.onload = function (){updateSelect(<?=$count ?>);}
```

or by an ajax like this

```
<script>
function updateSelect(options){

var x = document.getElementById("selector");

if (x.length > 0) {
    for (i = options; i < x.length+1; i++){
        x.remove(options);
    }
} 
}
window.onload=function(){
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    var count = xhttp.responseText;
    updateSelect(count);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "url/to/get/count", true);
xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

Just use a simple loop to inject the options onto the page before it is rendered. I'm going to assume you have an array of option data to pull from.

```
<?php 
    $optionData = array(
        array('value' => 'saab', 'label' => 'saab'),
        ...
    );
?>

<select class="form-control multiplechose_questionTypes" name="selector[]" id="selector" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < count; $i++) {
            echo '<option value="' . $optionData[$i]["value"] . '">' . $optionData[$i]["label"] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to add option dynamically using javascript and PHP,

Option 1: Using Javascript - I am assuming select options is static

Step 1:  you need set selects option in json variable
Step 2 : Assign $count php variable into js count variable
Step 3 : Based on your js count variable you can create select options and insert into select element.

Option 2: Using PHP and Ajax

Step 1:  You need create a ajax request and send $count php varible 
Step 2 : Create PHP function which will call on ajax req and render your options as HTML.
Step 3 : Set this option HTML string into target select element id.

Answer (score 1):

```
select your element first
var select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

onclick or any other event add this functionality
function addOption()
{ 
var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'YourValue';
    opt.innerHTML = 'Option1';
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$vehicles = array("saab"=>"Saab","fiat"=>"Fiat","audi"=>"Audi");
$count  = count_answers_belongToOne_question($questionNumber);
array_splice($vehicles , $count);
?>
<select class="form-control multiplechose_questionTypes" name="selector[]" id="selector" > 
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
   <?php
       foreach ($vehicles as $key => $value) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $value;?></option>            
   <?php
       }
   ?>   
 </select>
```

Comment: Using `array_splice` is a destructive modification to the original collection. This should be avoided for UI based operations.